# Can 404 errors be called as wasted computation power ? Can a lot of 404 errors have an effect on servers ?

Tags: http-status-code-404

Let's say that a lot of people use a link where there's nothing on the server and it throws a 404 status code. Would it mean that the server would have to search its entire database for that resource before throwing a 404 error ?

Would it mean that the server has wasted its power on searching for something that doesn't exist ? How much of an effect would it have on the server's performance or how many of these futile searching attempts would it take to make a dent on server's performance ?

Comment: 404 is low use of ressources for the server: server check if the requested file exist, if not it throw 404 error page.

Comment: Is there a limit on number of 404 messages a server can handle before affecting the server's performance ?

Comment: It depend on your server performance, but your server will easier deliver 404 page than other static/dynamic pages. If you have high amount of 404 pages, you should check why, cause web server are there to deliver content, and not 404 pages :P